# How can I start bitcoind without blockchain synchronization?

Tags: bitcoind, network, synchronization

Suppose I make a locked wallet with 50000 pre-generated addresses.

As long as I researched, **only way I can collect those 50000 addresses using RPC and "getnewaddress"**. Feel free to correct me.

I understand this will took several hours or days, so I can set this up on some VPS and let it run.

For this I do not need blockchain to be synchronized.

How can I start bitcoind without blockchain synchronization?

I am thinking about "connect" option or testnet, but both looks like a hack.

Comment: You could also run `dumpwallet`, which would have the addresses in the resulting dump - although at this point, you might want to look into a small script to generate an HD wallet, it will likely go a lot faster.

Comment: dumpwallet requires passphrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is to use the `-connect` option. You can do `-connect=0` or `-noconnect` (they mean the same thing) and Bitcoin Core will not try to automatically connect to any other node.

Comment: works like a charm. added connect=0 in the config file